# Combine different rows

Tags: r

Consider a dataframe of the form

```
                 id       start        end
2009.36220 65693384  2010-03-20 2010-07-04
2010.36221 65693592  2010-01-01 2010-12-31
2010.36222 65698250  2010-01-01 2010-12-31
2010.36223 65704349  2010-01-01 2010-12-31
```

where I have around *20k* observations per year for 15 years.

I need to combine the rows by the following rule:

- if for the same `id`, there exists a record that ends at the last day of the year
- and a record that starts at the first day of the following year

then
- create a new row with `start` value of the earlier row and `end` value of the later year
- and delete the two original rows

Given that the same `id` can be visible several times (since I have more than 2 years) I will then just iterate over the script several time to combine different ids that have for example 4 rows in consecutive years that satisfy the condition.

**The Question**

I'd know how to program this in an iterative manner, where I would go over every single row and check if there's a row with a start date next year *somewhere in the whole data frame* that corresponds to the end date this year - but that's extremely slow and non satisfying from an aesthetic point of view. I'm a very beginner with `R`, so I have no clue of where to even look to do such a thing in a more efficient manner - I'm open for any suggestion.

Comment: I can think of a couple of ways to solve this (and none of them involve iterating).  But it would be easier to help if you included data that actually had multiple IDs. Can you include an example with a few more rows?

Comment: Could you paste: dput(head(yourdata, 20))?

Comment: @Vlo that will not give you data for several years - I suppose that's what you're after. Right now I am given test data for the code that contains around 30k rows per year. If I knew a way to display 10 rows for consecutive years that satisfy the merge criterion, I would have provided that.

Answer (score 0):

Warning: this kind of code with `rbind()` is cancerous, but this is the easiest solution I could think of. Let `df` be your data.

```
df$start = as.POSIXct(df$start)
df$end = as.POSIXct(df$end)
df2 = data.frame()
for (i in unique(df$id)){
  s = subset(df, id==i)
  df2 = rbind(df2, c(id, min(s$start), max(s$end)))
}
```